# How to send an email about the purchase of a product with custom fields

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a custom Shopify product builder. The fields in it have name="properties[]" so after the order the seller sees in Orders all the fields that the buyer filled in. But the buyer receives a product by email without these fields, only its picture. Is it possible to send a purchase notification via email along with custom fields and not just with a product picture and price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your emails template in Store > Settings > Notifications.

You will need to have some knowledge in .liquid in order to insert the following code:

```
<!-- Start Custom Code -->
{%- for prop in line.properties -%}
<div>                     
    <span>{{ prop.first }}: </span>
    <span> {{ prop.last }}  </span>
<div>  
{%- endfor -%}   
<!-- End Custom Code -->
```

Be sure to save the previous template before editing.